# Invalid Toolchain - Xcode 9 GM Seed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta

I previous developed apps in xcode 9 beta versions but downloaded the GM seed yesterday. I have "cleaned" the projects, re-built and uploaded them for processing.

I am still receiving the following automated message from apple.

> Invalid Toolchain - New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.

Will I need to re-build and upload when the final xcode version is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have still a beta of macOS which is not in GM status? Wait for the GM of OS X.

Comment: With the GM of 10.13 (17A362a) Apps are now accepted